# SharePoint Modern Page - Quick Launch - Any way to add borders around the links?

Tags: navigation, custom, modern-pages, quick-launch

I've been tasked to try and recreate an html hard-coded navigation menu onto an SP Modern Team Site homepage.  The functionality (cascading sublinks) is already there, which is great.  But I need to either be able to add color fill to the links, or at least add border boxes around them.  Here's my quick launch:

[image]

Also if there's a way to wrap text, that would be cool.

Anyhelp to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's not supported:

[Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages)